# 同一ファイル内容を変更してAssetDatabase.Refresh()を連続して呼び出した時の問題

Tags: unity3d

```
            string resFile = "test";
            string outFile = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/" + resFile;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            { // data write.
                byte[] data = new byte[i == 0 ? 16 : 200];
                File.WriteAllBytes(outFile + ".bytes", data);
                AssetDatabase.Refresh(); // refresh
            }
            TextAsset byteAsset = Resources.Load(resFile) as TextAsset;
            Debug.Log(byteAsset.bytes.Length);
```

上記のコードの期待する結果としては最後のLog表示に200が帰ってきてほしいのですが16が返ってきます。

以下の様にAssetDatabaseの呼び出しをループの外に出して最後に1度だけ呼ぶようにしてやれば期待する200の値が返ってくるようになりました。

```
                File.WriteAllBytes(outFile + ".bytes", data);
            }
            AssetDatabase.Refresh(); // refresh
            TextAsset byteAsset = Resources.Load(resFile) as TextAsset;
            Debug.Log(byteAsset.bytes.Length);
```

AssetDatabase.Refresh();は遅延のあるAPIなのでしょうか？
※遅延つきかと思った理由として、最初のコードのRefreshの前に1秒waitを入れたら期待値が返きた為です。

この症状はUnity 4.5で確認しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity5(beta)で試してみたところ、本件の問題が発生しなくなっていました。

Comment: もしまだ回答を募集中でしたら、質問欄の方に疑問が書かれている方がわかりやすいです! > 不具合が治ったのでしょうか？

Comment: 確かに曖昧な回答の書き方をしていました。
修正されていたので、その旨をきちんと記載しておきます！
ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: 確認しました、ありがとうございます！

Comment: ご自分で解決なさったのであれば、チェックマークを押してベストアンサーにすることで、未解決の質問から表示させなくすることができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！チェックマークを教えておきます。